# How to detect duplicate records with sub table records

Tags: sql

Let's say I'm creating an address book in which the main table contains the basic contact information and a phone number sub table -

```
Contact
===============
Id         [PK]
Name

PhoneNumber
===============
Id         [PK]
Contact_Id [FK]
Number
```

So, a Contact record may have zero or more related records in the PhoneNumber table. There is no constraint on uniqueness of any column other than the primary keys. In fact, this must be true because:

1. Two contacts having different names may share a phone number, and
2. Two contacts may have the same name but different phone numbers.

I want to import a large dataset which may contain duplicate records into my database and then filter out the duplicates using SQL. The rules for identifying duplicate records are simple ... they must share the same name and the same number of phone records having the same content.

Of course, this works quite effectively for selecting duplicates from the Contact table but doesn't help me to detect actual duplicates given my rules:

```
SELECT * FROM Contact
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 'x' FROM Contact t2 
     WHERE t2.Name = Contact.Name AND
           t2.Id > Contact.Id);
```

It seems as if what I want is a logical extension to what I already have, but I must be overlooking it. Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: you need to join the two tables, group by name, and number and `count(Id)`, then use a `HAVING` clause to get `COUNT(Id) > 1`

Comment: There should be a unique constraint on `(PhoneNumber.Contact_Id, PhoneNumber.Number)`, though. Otherwise you are facing the risk of storing the same number for the same contact ID several times (which, by the way, might make things more difficult in determining duplicate *sets* of data when importing that large dataset).

Comment: Andriy's comment is a good one. If, however, the utility wants to ingest the data with minimal validation up-front and clean it up later, it might be better to create a set of cache tables without such constraints which, as he says, would be good on a final table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author stated the requirement of "two people being the same person" as:

1. Having the same name and
2. Having the same number of phone numbers **and** all of which are the same.

So the problem is a bit more complex than it seems (or maybe I just overthought it).

Sample data and (an ugly one, I know, but the general idea is there) a sample query which I tested on below test data which seems to be working correctly (I'm using Oracle 11g R2):

```
CREATE TABLE contact (
  id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR2(40))
;

CREATE TABLE phone_number (
  id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  contact_id REFERENCES contact (id),
  phone VARCHAR2(10)
);

INSERT INTO contact (id, name) VALUES (1, 'John');
INSERT INTO contact (id, name) VALUES (2, 'John');
INSERT INTO contact (id, name) VALUES (3, 'Peter');
INSERT INTO contact (id, name) VALUES (4, 'Peter');
INSERT INTO contact (id, name) VALUES (5, 'Mike');
INSERT INTO contact (id, name) VALUES (6, 'Mike');
INSERT INTO contact (id, name) VALUES (7, 'Mike');

INSERT INTO phone_number (id, contact_id, phone) VALUES (1, 1, '123'); -- John having number 123
INSERT INTO phone_number (id, contact_id, phone) VALUES (2, 1, '456'); -- John having number 456

INSERT INTO phone_number (id, contact_id, phone) VALUES (3, 2, '123'); -- John the second having number 123
INSERT INTO phone_number (id, contact_id, phone) VALUES (4, 2, '456'); -- John the second having number 456

INSERT INTO phone_number (id, contact_id, phone) VALUES (5, 3, '123'); -- Peter having number 123
INSERT INTO phone_number (id, contact_id, phone) VALUES (6, 3, '456'); -- Peter having number 123
INSERT INTO phone_number (id, contact_id, phone) VALUES (7, 3, '789'); -- Peter having number 123

INSERT INTO phone_number (id, contact_id, phone) VALUES (8, 4, '456'); -- Peter the second having number 456

INSERT INTO phone_number (id, contact_id, phone) VALUES (9, 5, '123'); -- Mike having number 456
INSERT INTO phone_number (id, contact_id, phone) VALUES (10, 5, '456'); -- Mike having number 456

INSERT INTO phone_number (id, contact_id, phone) VALUES (11, 6, '123'); -- Mike the second having number 456
INSERT INTO phone_number (id, contact_id, phone) VALUES (12, 6, '789'); -- Mike the second having number 456

-- Mike the third having no number
COMMIT;

-- does not meet the requirements described in the question - will return Peter when it should not
SELECT DISTINCT c.name
  FROM contact c JOIN phone_number pn ON (pn.contact_id = c.id)
GROUP BY name, phone_number
HAVING COUNT(c.id) > 1
;

-- returns correct results for provided test data
-- take all people that have a namesake in contact table and
-- take all this person's phone numbers that this person's namesake also has
-- finally (outer query) check that the number of both persons' phone numbers is the same and
-- the number of the same phone numbers is equal to the number of (either) person's phone numbers
SELECT c1_id, name
  FROM (
    SELECT c1.id AS c1_id, c1.name, c2.id AS c2_id, COUNT(1) AS cnt
      FROM contact c1
        JOIN contact c2 ON (c2.id != c1.id AND c2.name = c1.name)
        JOIN phone_number pn ON (pn.contact_id = c1.id)
    WHERE
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM phone_number
              WHERE contact_id = c2.id
                AND phone = pn.phone)
    GROUP BY c1.id, c1.name, c2.id
  )
WHERE cnt = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM phone_number WHERE contact_id = c1_id)
  AND (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM phone_number WHERE contact_id = c1_id) = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM phone_number WHERE contact_id = c2_id)
;

-- cleanup
DROP TABLE phone_number;
DROP TABLE contact;
```

Check at SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/36cdf/1

**Edited**

Answer to author's comment: Of course I didn't take that into account... here's a revised solution:

```
-- new test data
INSERT INTO contact (id, name) VALUES (8, 'Jane');
INSERT INTO contact (id, name) VALUES (9, 'Jane');

SELECT c1_id, name
  FROM (
    SELECT c1.id AS c1_id, c1.name, c2.id AS c2_id, COUNT(1) AS cnt
      FROM contact c1
        JOIN contact c2 ON (c2.id != c1.id AND c2.name = c1.name)
        LEFT JOIN phone_number pn ON (pn.contact_id = c1.id)
    WHERE pn.contact_id IS NULL
      OR EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM phone_number
              WHERE contact_id = c2.id
                AND phone = pn.phone)
    GROUP BY c1.id, c1.name, c2.id
  )
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM phone_number WHERE contact_id = c1_id) IN (0, cnt)
  AND (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM phone_number WHERE contact_id = c1_id) = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM phone_number WHERE contact_id = c2_id)
;
```

We allow a situation when there are no phone numbers (LEFT JOIN) and in outer query we now compare the number of person's phone numbers - it must either be equal to 0, or the number returned from the inner query.

Comment: Thanks! That's on the right track, I think. But what about the case in which there are zero associated phone records for a contact record?

Comment: Zero associated records means there are no duplicates.  Are you not looking for duplicates?

Comment: Well they share the same name and have the same number of phone numbers... If by the comment the author meant:

"What will this query return when there will be people with the same name, both having no phone numbers?"

Then:

- The first version of the query will not return them.
- The revised query will.

Comment: Indeed, that is what I meant. This perfectly answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

In my question, I created a greatly simplified schema that reflects the real-world problem I'm solving. Przemyslaw's answer is indeed a correct one and did what I was asking both with the sample schema and, when extended, with the real one.

But, after doing some experiments with the real schema and a larger (~10k records) dataset, I found that performance was an issue. I don't claim to be an index guru, but I wasn't able to find a better combination of indices than what was already in the schema.

So, I came up with an alternate solution which fills the same requirements but executes in a small fraction (< 10%) of the time, at least using SQLite3 - my production engine. In hopes that it may assist someone else, I'll offer it as an alternative answer to my question.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Contact;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PhoneNumber;

CREATE TABLE Contact (
  Id    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  Name  TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE PhoneNumber (
  Id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  Contact_Id  INTEGER REFERENCES Contact (Id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
  Number      TEXT
);

INSERT INTO Contact (Id, Name) VALUES
  (1, 'John Smith'),
  (2, 'John Smith'),
  (3, 'John Smith'),
  (4, 'Jane Smith'),
  (5, 'Bob Smith'),
  (6, 'Bob Smith');

INSERT INTO PhoneNumber (Id, Contact_Id, Number) VALUES
  (1, 1, '555-1212'),
  (2, 1, '222-1515'),
  (3, 2, '222-1515'),
  (4, 2, '555-1212'),
  (5, 3, '111-2525'),
  (6, 4, '111-2525');

COMMIT;

SELECT *
FROM Contact c1
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM Contact c2
  WHERE c2.Id > c1.Id
    AND c2.Name = c1.Name
    AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PhoneNumber WHERE Contact_Id = c2.Id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PhoneNumber WHERE Contact_Id = c1.Id)
    AND (
      SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM PhoneNumber p1
      WHERE p1.Contact_Id = c2.Id
        AND EXISTS (
          SELECT 1
          FROM PhoneNumber p2
          WHERE p2.Contact_Id = c1.Id
            AND p2.Number = p1.Number
        )
    ) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PhoneNumber WHERE Contact_Id = c1.Id)
)
;
```

The results are as expected:

```
Id     Name
====== =============
1      John Smith
5      Bob Smith
```

Other engines are bound to have differing performance which may be quite acceptable. This solution seems to work quite well with SQLite for this schema.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword "having" is your friend.  The generic use is:

```
select field1, field2, count(*) records
from whereever
where whatever
group by field1, field2
having records > 1
```

Whether or not you can use the alias in the having clause depends on the database engine.  You should be able to apply this basic principle to your situation.